# C++11: no matching function for call to constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to implement a struct for an L-System and get an error when initializing my LSystem object. There seems to be a problem with the constructor.

The header file LSystem.h:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct LSystem {
    // member variable
    //-----------------------------------------------
    std::vector<std::string> var_;
    std::vector<std::string> cons_;
    std::vector<std::string> axiom_;
    std::vector< std::vector<std::string> > rules_; //have to be in the same order as their variables in var_
    unsigned int counter_;


    // ctor
    //-----------------------------------------------
    // parameterless ctor
    //LSystem ();
    // parameterized ctor
    LSystem (const std::vector<std::string> &var, const std::vector<std::string> &cons,
        const std::vector<std::string> &axiom, const std::vector< std::vector<std::string> > &rules,
        const unsigned int counter);
    // copy ctor
    LSystem (const LSystem &s);

    // member-functions
    //-----------------------------------------------
    void apply();
    void print_state() const;
};
```

The source code file LSystem.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>    // std::find
#include <iterator>

#include "LSystem.h"

//Ctor
LSystem::LSystem(const std::vector<std::string> &var,
    const std::vector<std::string> &cons,
    const std::vector<std::string> &axiom,
    const std::vector< std::vector<std::string> > &rules,
    const unsigned int counter)
    : var_ {var}, cons_ {cons}, axiom_ {axiom}, rules_ {rules}, counter_ {counter} { }

LSystem::LSystem (const LSystem &s)
    : var_ {s.var_}, cons_ {s.cons_}, axiom_ {s.axiom_}, rules_ {s.rules_}, counter_ {s.counter_} { }

//member functions
//apply: applies the rule on the current axiom

void LSystem::apply() {
   std::vector<std::string> tmp;
    for (std::string s1 : axiom_) {
        unsigned int pos = std::find(var_.begin(), var_.end(), s1) - var_.begin();
        for (std::string s2 : rules_[pos]) {
            tmp.push_back(s2);
        }
    }
    axiom_ = tmp;
    counter_ += 1;
}

//print_stat: prints the current axiom
void LSystem::print_state() const {
    for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator i = axiom_.begin(); i != axiom_.end(); ++i)
    std::cout << *i << " ";
}
```

The main file Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "LSystem.h"


int main() {
    /*
    2.1 Koch curve
    variables : F
    constants : + -
    start: F
    rules: F ! F+F-F-F+F
    F means "draw while moving one step forward", + means "turn left 90°", - means
"turn right 90°"
    */
    unsigned int rounds = 5;
    unsigned int counter = 0;

    std::vector<std::string> Kvar = {"F"};
    std::vector<std::string> Kcons = {"+", "-"};
    std::string Kstart = {"F"};
    std::vector< std::vector<std::string> > Krules = { {"F", "+", "F", "-", "F", "-", "F", "+", "F"} }; //have to be in the same order as their variables in var_

    LSystem Koch = LSystem(Kvar, Kcons, Kstart, Krules, counter); // line with error

    while (Koch.counter_ < rounds) {
        Koch.apply();
        Koch.print_state();
    }
}
```

I get the error on the line indicated in the Main.cpp

`no matching function for call to ‘LSystem::LSystem(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&, std::__cxx11::string&, std::vector<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >&, unsigned int&)’
  LSystem Koch = LSystem(Kvar, Kcons, Kstart, Krules, counter);`

I am a beginner in C++ and I really don't see what is wrong with the constructor. Also, I am not sure if I would need a parameterless constructor here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
LSystem Koch = LSystem(Kvar, Kcons, Kstart, Krules, counter); // line with error
```

is trying to invoke

```
LSystem(v<s>, v<s>, s, v<v<s>>, unsigned int)
                  ^^^^
```

(using `v` for `std::vector` and `s` for `std::string` so that I can fit on one window). Your constructor for `LSystem` is:

```
LSystem(v<s>, v<s>, v<s>, v<v<s>>, unsigned int);
                  ^^^^^^^
```

Your `Kstart` is the wrong type. Needs to be a `std::vector<std::string>` instead of a `std::string`.

---

Side-note, there's no reason for copy-initialization. Use direct initialization. And prefer to name your variables with a lower-case letter to differentiate them from your types:

```
LSystem koch(kvar, kcons, kstart, krules, counter);
```

Comment: Thanks :)! Why did I get downvoted for my question? I thought I expressed myself clearly and provided a complete record...